# Getting hash values as an array keeping order in ruby 1.8.3

Tags: ruby

I'm doing:

```
{:a => 'hello', :c => 'lovely', :b => 'word'}.values
```

It returns:

```
[0] "hello",
[1] "word",
[2] "lovely"
```

Why did the order change? Any way to easily return the values in the order they were defined in hash?

Comment: Because you are using a version of Ruby that preceded v1.9. Before 1.9 (which is now 7 years old!) there was no guarantee on the order of keys. Ergo, upgrade.

Comment: Cannot be reproduced (unless you are using an unusually old version, in which case you failed to mention).

Comment: A common thought would be that is that Hashes are when order doesn't matter, and Arrays should be used when order does matter. But if you insisted on using the old version of ruby that you're using, perhaps you could look into manually sorting the Hash keys or values to do what you want?

Comment: @TonyDiNitto, I can't agree. I've found many uses for hashes where the order of the keys is required. The simple fact that keys were given a type of order in 1.9 is testament to its value. Also, I don't think it's helpful to try to oversimplify the choice of using an array or a hash, as there are several important differences besides order, as you well know.

Comment: @Cary Swoveland I agree with you Cary. I've found a lot of use in having Hashes sorted, which I why I suggested that. I was just mentioning it was a "common thought", not my own. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails implements an OrderedHash for Ruby version < 1.9. You can consider implementing it if you're not using Rails.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/OrderedHash